# Pandas bitwise filtering gives different results with and without parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to filter out some records that don't satisfy certain criteria:

```
cond1=df['ap_lo'] <= df['ap_hi']
cond2=df['height'] >= df['height'].quantile(q=0.025)
cond3=df['height'] <= df['height'].quantile(q=.957)
cond4=df['weight'] >= df['weight'].quantile(q=0.025)
cond5=df['weight'] <= df['weight'].quantile(q=0.975)
```

This gives the following percentage of the original data:

```
filtered_df=df[cond1 & cond2 & cond3 & cond4 & cond5]
print(filtered_df.shape[0] / df.shape[0]) 
>>>0.8865
```

What surprised me is that when I try the same but using parenthesis between conditions instead of predefining the conditions variables I get different results:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['ap_lo'] <= df['ap_hi']) & 
                 (df['height'] >= df['height'].quantile(0.025)) &
                 (df['height'] <= df['height'].quantile(0.975)) &
                 (df['weight'] >= df['weight'].quantile(0.025)) & 
                 (df['weight'] <= df['weight'].quantile(0.975))]
print(filtered_df.shape[0] / df.shape[0])
>>> 0.9037
```

What is going on? I don't think that is something related to the order in which these operations are performed because AND is associative and commutative as far as I remember...

Comment: Your first snippet has `.quantile(q=.957)` in `cond3` while your second snippet has `.quantile(0.975)` in the third condition. Does this cause the difference?

Comment: No, this shouldn't be the problem, you can quickly verify it by `np.equal(0.1, .1)`

Comment: Make sure that in both cases your `filtered_df` has exactly the same data. Specially if you're using the jupyter notebook. In Jupyter is very easy to run blocks of code in different orders (not from top to bottom) and lose that of the state of your variables (what has alredy been modified and what has not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@luuk's comment is correct; the problem is you've transposed digits in your second definition of the third condition.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(size=(250,4)), columns=['ap_hi', 'ap_lo', 'height', 'weight'])

a = (df['height'] <= df['height'].quantile(q=0.975))
b = (df['height'] <= df['height'].quantile(q=0.957))
print((a == b).all())
```